# How to get value from dictionary using key from another dictionary as the name

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries. I need to retrieve the values from 2nd dictionary based on the key from the first dictionary.

2nd dictionary name is key of 1st dictionary. But when i get the key from the 1st dictionary, its type is string. When i used the same to get the values from the 2nd dictionary, I get AttributeError

```
dictA = {
    "key1": [val1, val2, val3],
    "key2": [val4, val5, val6],
    "key3": [val7, val8, val9]
}

key1 = {
    "A": "value",
    "B": "value",
    "C": "value"
}

for key, value in dictA.items():
    for val in value:
        if val == "val1":
           newKey = key

val = newKey.get("A")
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Is there a way to achieve by converting string object to dict.

Apologies for my vague explanation

Comment: Seems that you can use a nested dictionary to make your life easier. Also, the question you are asking is not clear. Are the values in the first and second dictionary different?

Comment: @DerekLangley Yes, values are different in both the dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

Store your `key1` dict (and all other `key...` dicts) in a larger dict.

```py
keys = {
  'key1': {
    'A': 'value',
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, you can access that using `newKey`:

```py
val = keys[newKey]['A']
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael, that helps

Answer (score 1):

Instantiation:

```py
nested_dict = { 
   'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
   'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}
}
```

Access:

```py
value = nested_dict['dictA']['name']
```

These are excerpts from this awesome [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary) on nested dictionaries.